# Converting multi-geometry GML with ogr2ogr not working

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, gml, citygml

I am having difficulties with GML loading in PostGIS with ogr2ogr.

It is a GML of buildingparts containing both polygons and (label)-points. 
In this example (below) I have a selection of 9 objects. The number of polygons is 9 and there are 6 point-objects. So there are 6 object with both polygon and point geometry.

```
ogr2ogr -skipfailures -lco OVERWRITE=yes --config PG_USE_COPY YES -gt 50000 -lco LAUNDER=NO -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=xxxx user=xxxx dbname=xxxx password=xxxx" "buildingpart.gml" -sql "select * from buildingpart where OGR_GEOMETRY = 'MULTIPOLYGON'" -nln test.buildingpart_multipolygon_selection

ogr2ogr -skipfailures -lco OVERWRITE=yes --config PG_USE_COPY YES -gt 50000 -lco LAUNDER=NO -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=xxxx user=xxxx dbname=xxxx password=xxxx" "buildingpart.gml" -sql "select * from buildingpart where OGR_GEOMETRY = 'POINT'" -nln test.buildingpart_point_selection
```

Unfortunately without result.

Is anyone familiar with this problem of multiple geometry in GML. And is there a solution?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CityModel xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
                xmlns:imgeo="http://www.geostandaarden.nl/imgeo/2.1"
                xmlns:lu="http://www.opengis.net/citygml/landuse/2.0"
                xmlns:tra="http://www.opengis.net/citygml/transportation/2.0"
                xmlns:tun="http://www.opengis.net/citygml/tunnel/2.0"
                xmlns:veg="http://www.opengis.net/citygml/vegetation/2.0"
                xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                xmlns:wat="http://www.opengis.net/citygml/waterbody/2.0"
                xmlns:bri="http://www.opengis.net/citygml/bridge/2.0"
                xmlns:bui="http://www.opengis.net/citygml/building/2.0"
                xmlns:cif="http://www.opengis.net/citygml/cityfurniture/2.0"
                xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/citygml/2.0"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.geostandaarden.nl/imgeo/2.1 http://schemas.geonovum.nl/imgeo/2.1/imgeo-2.1.1.xsd"><cityObjectMember><BuildingPart xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/citygml/building/2.0" gml:id="A23E12F79B4843EE4E0531F0B5B0AB389"><creationDate xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/citygml/2.0">2014-01-21</creationDate><imgeo:identificatie><imgeo:NEN3610ID><imgeo:namespace>NL.IMGeo</imgeo:namespace><imgeo:lokaalID>G0171.0e18660393856e9ce0540012799ed965</imgeo:lokaalID></imgeo:NEN3610ID></imgeo:identificatie><imgeo:relatieveHoogteligging>0</imgeo:relatieveHoogteligging><imgeo:LV-publicatiedatum>2015-11-06T00:58:34.000</imgeo:LV-publicatiedatum><imgeo:inOnderzoek>false</imgeo:inOnderzoek><imgeo:tijdstipRegistratie>2015-07-08T13:18:24.000</imgeo:tijdstipRegistratie><imgeo:bgt-status codeSpace="http://www.geostandaarden.nl/imgeo/def/2.1#Status">bestaand</imgeo:bgt-status><imgeo:plus-status codeSpace="http://www.geostandaarden.nl/imgeo/def/2.1#VoidReasonValue">geenWaarde</imgeo:plus-status><imgeo:bronhouder>G0171</imgeo:bronhouder><imgeo:identificatieBAGPND>0171100000015950</imgeo:identificatieBAGPND><imgeo:geometrie2dGrondvlak><gml:MultiSurface srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992"><gml:surfaceMember><gml:Polygon><gml:exterior><gml:LinearRing><gml:posList srsDimension="2" count="6">178913.520 525128.784 178907.630 525127.150 178909.736 525119.688 178915.401 525121.259 178915.554 525121.301 178913.520 525128.784</gml:posList></gml:LinearRing></gml:exterior></gml:Polygon></gml:surfaceMember></gml:MultiSurface></imgeo:geometrie2dGrondvlak><imgeo:nummeraanduidingreeks><imgeo:Nummeraanduidingreeks><imgeo:nummeraanduidingreeks><imgeo:Label><imgeo:tekst>16</imgeo:tekst><imgeo:positie><imgeo:Labelpositie><imgeo:plaatsingspunt><gml:Point srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992"><gml:pos>178911.348 525126.313</gml:pos></gml:Point></imgeo:plaatsingspunt><imgeo:hoek>-15.5</imgeo:hoek></imgeo:Labelpositie></imgeo:positie></imgeo:Label></imgeo:nummeraanduidingreeks><imgeo:identificatieBAGVBOLaagsteHuisnummer>0171010000018912</imgeo:identificatieBAGVBOLaagsteHuisnummer></imgeo:Nummeraanduidingreeks></imgeo:nummeraanduidingreeks></BuildingPart></cityObjectMember><cityObjectMember><BuildingPart xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/citygml/building/2.0" gml:id="A23E12F79B4943EE4E0531F0B5B0AB389"><creationDate xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/citygml/2.0">2014-01-21</creationDate><imgeo:identificatie><imgeo:NEN3610ID><imgeo:namespace>NL.IMGeo</imgeo:namespace><imgeo:lokaalID>G0171.0e18660393c36e9ce0540012799ed965</imgeo:lokaalID></imgeo:NEN3610ID></imgeo:identificatie><imgeo:relatieveHoogteligging>0</imgeo:relatieveHoogteligging><imgeo:LV-publicatiedatum>2015-11-06T00:58:34.000</imgeo:LV-publicatiedatum><imgeo:inOnderzoek>false</imgeo:inOnderzoek><imgeo:tijdstipRegistratie>2015-07-08T13:18:24.000</imgeo:tijdstipRegistratie><imgeo:bgt-status codeSpace="http://www.geostandaarden.nl/imgeo/def/2.1#Status">bestaand</imgeo:bgt-status><imgeo:plus-status codeSpace="http://www.geostandaarden.nl/imgeo/def/2.1#VoidReasonValue">geenWaarde</imgeo:plus-status><imgeo:bronhouder>G0171</imgeo:bronhouder><imgeo:identificatieBAGPND>0171100000031928</imgeo:identificatieBAGPND><imgeo:geometrie2dGrondvlak><gml:MultiSurface srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992"><gml:surfaceMember><gml:Polygon><gml:exterior><gml:LinearRing><gml:posList srsDimension="2" count="5">179008.703 525138.457 179009.717 525134.804 179011.853 525135.398 179010.835 525139.051 179008.703 525138.457</gml:posList></gml:LinearRing></gml:exterior></gml:Polygon></gml:surfaceMember></gml:MultiSurface></imgeo:geometrie2dGrondvlak></BuildingPart></cityObjectMember><cityObjectMember><BuildingPart xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/citygml/building/2.0" gml:id="A23E12F79B4A43EE4E0531F0B5B0AB389"><creationDate xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/citygml/2.0">2014-01-21</creationDate><imgeo:identificatie><imgeo:NEN3610ID><imgeo:namespace>NL.IMGeo</imgeo:namespace><imgeo:lokaalID>G0171.0e18660393c96e9ce0540012799ed965</imgeo:lokaalID></imgeo:NEN3610ID></imgeo:identificatie><imgeo:relatieveHoogteligging>0</imgeo:relatieveHoogteligging><imgeo:LV-publicatiedatum>2015-11-06T00:58:34.000</imgeo:LV-publicatiedatum><imgeo:inOnderzoek>false</imgeo:inOnderzoek><imgeo:tijdstipRegistratie>2015-07-08T13:18:24.000</imgeo:tijdstipRegistratie><imgeo:bgt-status codeSpace="http://www.geostandaarden.nl/imgeo/def/2.1#Status">bestaand</imgeo:bgt-status><imgeo:plus-status codeSpace="http://www.geostandaarden.nl/imgeo/def/2.1#VoidReasonValue">geenWaarde</imgeo:plus-status><imgeo:bronhouder>G0171</imgeo:bronhouder><imgeo:identificatieBAGPND>0171100000031915</imgeo:identificatieBAGPND><imgeo:geometrie2dGrondvlak><gml:MultiSurface srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992"><gml:surfaceMember><gml:Polygon><gml:exterior><gml:LinearRing><gml:posList srsDimension="2" count="5">179015.484 525077.419 179016.323 525074.452 179021.459 525075.865 179020.641 525078.838 179015.484 525077.419</gml:posList></gml:LinearRing></gml:exterior></gml:Polygon></gml:surfaceMember></gml:MultiSurface></imgeo:geometrie2dGrondvlak></BuildingPart></cityObjectMember>

                <cityObjectMember><BuildingPart xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/citygml/building/2.0" gml:id="A23E12F79B4B43EE4E0531F0B5B0AB389"><creationDate xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/citygml/2.0">2014-01-21</creationDate><imgeo:identificatie><imgeo:NEN3610ID><imgeo:namespace>NL.IMGeo</imgeo:namespace><imgeo:lokaalID>G0171.0e18660393da6e9ce0540012799ed965</imgeo:lokaalID></imgeo:NEN3610ID></imgeo:identificatie><imgeo:relatieveHoogteligging>0</imgeo:relatieveHoogteligging><imgeo:LV-publicatiedatum>2015-11-06T00:58:34.000</imgeo:LV-publicatiedatum><imgeo:inOnderzoek>false</imgeo:inOnderzoek><imgeo:tijdstipRegistratie>2015-07-08T13:18:24.000</imgeo:tijdstipRegistratie><imgeo:bgt-status codeSpace="http://www.geostandaarden.nl/imgeo/def/2.1#Status">bestaand</imgeo:bgt-status><imgeo:plus-status codeSpace="http://www.geostandaarden.nl/imgeo/def/2.1#VoidReasonValue">geenWaarde</imgeo:plus-status><imgeo:bronhouder>G0171</imgeo:bronhouder><imgeo:identificatieBAGPND>0171100000031742</imgeo:identificatieBAGPND><imgeo:geometrie2dGrondvlak><gml:MultiSurface srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992"><gml:surfaceMember><gml:Polygon><gml:exterior><gml:LinearRing><gml:posList srsDimension="2" count="5">178987.139 525126.996 178982.103 525125.598 178982.976 525122.550 178987.987 525123.941 178987.139 525126.996</gml:posList></gml:LinearRing></gml:exterior></gml:Polygon></gml:surfaceMember></gml:MultiSurface></imgeo:geometrie2dGrondvlak></BuildingPart></cityObjectMember>

                <cityObjectMember><BuildingPart xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/citygml/building/2.0" gml:id="A23E12F79B4C43EE4E0531F0B5B0AB389"><creationDate xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/citygml/2.0">2014-01-21</creationDate><imgeo:identificatie><imgeo:NEN3610ID><imgeo:namespace>NL.IMGeo</imgeo:namespace><imgeo:lokaalID>G0171.0e18660393a76e9ce0540012799ed965</imgeo:lokaalID></imgeo:NEN3610ID></imgeo:identificatie><imgeo:relatieveHoogteligging>0</imgeo:relatieveHoogteligging><imgeo:LV-publicatiedatum>2015-11-06T00:58:34.000</imgeo:LV-publicatiedatum><imgeo:inOnderzoek>false</imgeo:inOnderzoek><imgeo:tijdstipRegistratie>2015-07-08T13:18:24.000</imgeo:tijdstipRegistratie><imgeo:bgt-status codeSpace="http://www.geostandaarden.nl/imgeo/def/2.1#Status">bestaand</imgeo:bgt-status><imgeo:plus-status codeSpace="http://www.geostandaarden.nl/imgeo/def/2.1#VoidReasonValue">geenWaarde</imgeo:plus-status><imgeo:bronhouder>G0171</imgeo:bronhouder><imgeo:identificatieBAGPND>0171100000015791</imgeo:identificatieBAGPND><imgeo:geometrie2dGrondvlak><gml:MultiSurface srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992"><gml:surfaceMember><gml:Polygon><gml:exterior><gml:LinearRing><gml:posList srsDimension="2" count="5">178993.057 525086.392 178986.903 525084.692 178988.800 525077.657 178994.951 525079.357 178993.057 525086.392</gml:posList></gml:LinearRing></gml:exterior></gml:Polygon></gml:surfaceMember></gml:MultiSurface></imgeo:geometrie2dGrondvlak><imgeo:nummeraanduidingreeks><imgeo:Nummeraanduidingreeks><imgeo:nummeraanduidingreeks><imgeo:Label><imgeo:tekst>34</imgeo:tekst><imgeo:positie><imgeo:Labelpositie><imgeo:plaatsingspunt><gml:Point srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992"><gml:pos>178990.230 525083.743</gml:pos></gml:Point></imgeo:plaatsingspunt><imgeo:hoek>-15.5</imgeo:hoek></imgeo:Labelpositie></imgeo:positie></imgeo:Label></imgeo:nummeraanduidingreeks><imgeo:identificatieBAGVBOLaagsteHuisnummer>0171010000011904</imgeo:identificatieBAGVBOLaagsteHuisnummer></imgeo:Nummeraanduidingreeks></imgeo:nummeraanduidingreeks></BuildingPart></cityObjectMember>

                <cityObjectMember><BuildingPart xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/citygml/building/2.0" gml:id="A23E12F79B5EB3EE4E0531F0B5B0AB389"><creationDate xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/citygml/2.0">2013-11-06</creationDate><imgeo:identificatie><imgeo:NEN3610ID><imgeo:namespace>NL.IMGeo</imgeo:namespace><imgeo:lokaalID>G0171.0e18660394ff6e9ce0540012799ed965</imgeo:lokaalID></imgeo:NEN3610ID></imgeo:identificatie><imgeo:relatieveHoogteligging>0</imgeo:relatieveHoogteligging><imgeo:LV-publicatiedatum>2015-11-06T00:58:34.000</imgeo:LV-publicatiedatum><imgeo:inOnderzoek>false</imgeo:inOnderzoek><imgeo:tijdstipRegistratie>2015-07-08T13:18:24.000</imgeo:tijdstipRegistratie><imgeo:bgt-status codeSpace="http://www.geostandaarden.nl/imgeo/def/2.1#Status">bestaand</imgeo:bgt-status><imgeo:plus-status codeSpace="http://www.geostandaarden.nl/imgeo/def/2.1#VoidReasonValue">geenWaarde</imgeo:plus-status><imgeo:bronhouder>G0171</imgeo:bronhouder><imgeo:identificatieBAGPND>0171100000011384</imgeo:identificatieBAGPND><imgeo:geometrie2dGrondvlak><gml:MultiSurface srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992"><gml:surfaceMember><gml:Polygon><gml:exterior><gml:LinearRing><gml:posList srsDimension="2" count="11">180142.660 524667.117 180142.150 524670.110 180135.483 524668.977 180135.516 524668.781 180135.901 524668.847 180136.976 524662.535 180143.262 524663.576 180146.328 524663.980 180145.954 524666.155 180145.700 524667.645 180142.660 524667.117</gml:posList></gml:LinearRing></gml:exterior></gml:Polygon></gml:surfaceMember></gml:MultiSurface></imgeo:geometrie2dGrondvlak><imgeo:nummeraanduidingreeks><imgeo:Nummeraanduidingreeks><imgeo:nummeraanduidingreeks><imgeo:Label><imgeo:tekst>13</imgeo:tekst><imgeo:positie><imgeo:Labelpositie><imgeo:plaatsingspunt><gml:Point srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992"><gml:pos>180139.027 524665.918</gml:pos></gml:Point></imgeo:plaatsingspunt><imgeo:hoek>80.3</imgeo:hoek></imgeo:Labelpositie></imgeo:positie></imgeo:Label></imgeo:nummeraanduidingreeks><imgeo:identificatieBAGVBOLaagsteHuisnummer>0171010000011411</imgeo:identificatieBAGVBOLaagsteHuisnummer></imgeo:Nummeraanduidingreeks></imgeo:nummeraanduidingreeks></BuildingPart></cityObjectMember><cityObjectMember><BuildingPart xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/citygml/building/2.0" gml:id="A23E12F79B5FB3EE4E0531F0B5B0AB389"><creationDate xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/citygml/2.0">2014-01-27</creationDate><imgeo:identificatie><imgeo:NEN3610ID><imgeo:namespace>NL.IMGeo</imgeo:namespace><imgeo:lokaalID>G0171.0e18660395576e9ce0540012799ed965</imgeo:lokaalID></imgeo:NEN3610ID></imgeo:identificatie><imgeo:relatieveHoogteligging>0</imgeo:relatieveHoogteligging><imgeo:LV-publicatiedatum>2015-11-06T00:58:34.000</imgeo:LV-publicatiedatum><imgeo:inOnderzoek>false</imgeo:inOnderzoek><imgeo:tijdstipRegistratie>2015-07-08T13:18:24.000</imgeo:tijdstipRegistratie><imgeo:bgt-status codeSpace="http://www.geostandaarden.nl/imgeo/def/2.1#Status">bestaand</imgeo:bgt-status><imgeo:plus-status codeSpace="http://www.geostandaarden.nl/imgeo/def/2.1#VoidReasonValue">geenWaarde</imgeo:plus-status><imgeo:bronhouder>G0171</imgeo:bronhouder><imgeo:identificatieBAGPND>0171100000021150</imgeo:identificatieBAGPND><imgeo:geometrie2dGrondvlak><gml:MultiSurface srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992"><gml:surfaceMember><gml:Polygon><gml:exterior><gml:LinearRing><gml:posList srsDimension="2" count="9">179916.313 526704.152 179919.782 526694.301 179925.317 526696.305 179924.508 526698.558 179927.449 526699.615 179925.085 526706.196 179922.181 526705.153 179921.829 526706.133 179916.313 526704.152</gml:posList></gml:LinearRing></gml:exterior></gml:Polygon></gml:surfaceMember></gml:MultiSurface></imgeo:geometrie2dGrondvlak><imgeo:nummeraanduidingreeks><imgeo:Nummeraanduidingreeks><imgeo:nummeraanduidingreeks><imgeo:Label><imgeo:tekst>13</imgeo:tekst><imgeo:positie><imgeo:Labelpositie><imgeo:plaatsingspunt><gml:Point srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992"><gml:pos>179921.453 526697.720</gml:pos></gml:Point></imgeo:plaatsingspunt><imgeo:hoek>-20</imgeo:hoek></imgeo:Labelpositie></imgeo:positie></imgeo:Label></imgeo:nummeraanduidingreeks><imgeo:identificatieBAGVBOLaagsteHuisnummer>0171010000014019</imgeo:identificatieBAGVBOLaagsteHuisnummer></imgeo:Nummeraanduidingreeks></imgeo:nummeraanduidingreeks></BuildingPart></cityObjectMember><cityObjectMember><BuildingPart xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/citygml/building/2.0" gml:id="A23E12F79B60B3EE4E0531F0B5B0AB389"><creationDate xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/citygml/2.0">2013-11-27</creationDate><imgeo:identificatie><imgeo:NEN3610ID><imgeo:namespace>NL.IMGeo</imgeo:namespace><imgeo:lokaalID>G0171.0e186603951f6e9ce0540012799ed965</imgeo:lokaalID></imgeo:NEN3610ID></imgeo:identificatie><imgeo:relatieveHoogteligging>0</imgeo:relatieveHoogteligging><imgeo:LV-publicatiedatum>2015-11-06T00:58:34.000</imgeo:LV-publicatiedatum><imgeo:inOnderzoek>false</imgeo:inOnderzoek><imgeo:tijdstipRegistratie>2015-07-08T13:18:24.000</imgeo:tijdstipRegistratie><imgeo:bgt-status codeSpace="http://www.geostandaarden.nl/imgeo/def/2.1#Status">bestaand</imgeo:bgt-status><imgeo:plus-status codeSpace="http://www.geostandaarden.nl/imgeo/def/2.1#VoidReasonValue">geenWaarde</imgeo:plus-status><imgeo:bronhouder>G0171</imgeo:bronhouder><imgeo:identificatieBAGPND>0171100000013543</imgeo:identificatieBAGPND><imgeo:geometrie2dGrondvlak><gml:MultiSurface srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992"><gml:surfaceMember><gml:Polygon><gml:exterior><gml:LinearRing><gml:posList srsDimension="2" count="7">180027.753 524894.546 180023.108 524894.059 180018.526 524893.578 180019.863 524881.265 180028.706 524882.207 180029.007 524882.239 180027.753 524894.546</gml:posList></gml:LinearRing></gml:exterior></gml:Polygon></gml:surfaceMember></gml:MultiSurface></imgeo:geometrie2dGrondvlak><imgeo:nummeraanduidingreeks><imgeo:Nummeraanduidingreeks><imgeo:nummeraanduidingreeks><imgeo:Label><imgeo:tekst>18-18B</imgeo:tekst><imgeo:positie><imgeo:Labelpositie><imgeo:plaatsingspunt><gml:Point srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992"><gml:pos>180020.480 524890.935</gml:pos></gml:Point></imgeo:plaatsingspunt><imgeo:hoek>-6.1</imgeo:hoek></imgeo:Labelpositie></imgeo:positie></imgeo:Label></imgeo:nummeraanduidingreeks><imgeo:identificatieBAGVBOLaagsteHuisnummer>0171010000032655</imgeo:identificatieBAGVBOLaagsteHuisnummer><imgeo:identificatieBAGVBOHoogsteHuisnummer>0171010000015372</imgeo:identificatieBAGVBOHoogsteHuisnummer></imgeo:Nummeraanduidingreeks></imgeo:nummeraanduidingreeks></BuildingPart></cityObjectMember><cityObjectMember><BuildingPart xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/citygml/building/2.0" gml:id="A23E12F79B61B3EE4E0531F0B5B0AB389"><creationDate xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/citygml/2.0">2013-12-12</creationDate><imgeo:identificatie><imgeo:NEN3610ID><imgeo:namespace>NL.IMGeo</imgeo:namespace><imgeo:lokaalID>G0171.0e186603952f6e9ce0540012799ed965</imgeo:lokaalID></imgeo:NEN3610ID></imgeo:identificatie><imgeo:relatieveHoogteligging>0</imgeo:relatieveHoogteligging><imgeo:LV-publicatiedatum>2015-11-06T00:58:34.000</imgeo:LV-publicatiedatum><imgeo:inOnderzoek>false</imgeo:inOnderzoek><imgeo:tijdstipRegistratie>2015-07-08T13:18:24.000</imgeo:tijdstipRegistratie><imgeo:bgt-status codeSpace="http://www.geostandaarden.nl/imgeo/def/2.1#Status">bestaand</imgeo:bgt-status><imgeo:plus-status codeSpace="http://www.geostandaarden.nl/imgeo/def/2.1#VoidReasonValue">geenWaarde</imgeo:plus-status><imgeo:bronhouder>G0171</imgeo:bronhouder><imgeo:identificatieBAGPND>0171100000015634</imgeo:identificatieBAGPND><imgeo:geometrie2dGrondvlak><gml:MultiSurface srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992"><gml:surfaceMember><gml:Polygon><gml:exterior><gml:LinearRing><gml:posList srsDimension="2" count="14">179606.841 525097.033 179603.783 525096.248 179603.875 525095.890 179601.035 525095.160 179599.656 525100.531 179593.206 525098.875 179594.471 525093.948 179593.670 525093.743 179594.189 525091.719 179604.265 525094.312 179604.694 525092.615 179604.795 525092.224 179607.855 525093.009 179606.841 525097.033</gml:posList></gml:LinearRing></gml:exterior></gml:Polygon></gml:surfaceMember></gml:MultiSurface></imgeo:geometrie2dGrondvlak><imgeo:nummeraanduidingreeks><imgeo:Nummeraanduidingreeks><imgeo:nummeraanduidingreeks><imgeo:Label><imgeo:tekst>24</imgeo:tekst><imgeo:positie><imgeo:Labelpositie><imgeo:plaatsingspunt><gml:Point srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992"><gml:pos>179596.864 525096.289</gml:pos></gml:Point></imgeo:plaatsingspunt><imgeo:hoek>75.6</imgeo:hoek></imgeo:Labelpositie></imgeo:positie></imgeo:Label></imgeo:nummeraanduidingreeks><imgeo:identificatieBAGVBOLaagsteHuisnummer>0171010000015907</imgeo:identificatieBAGVBOLaagsteHuisnummer></imgeo:Nummeraanduidingreeks></imgeo:nummeraanduidingreeks></BuildingPart></cityObjectMember></CityModel>
```

Comment: Which GDAL version do you have (`ogrinfo --version`)? Could you share a complete but small sample of data?

Comment: I am using GDAL 1.11.3, released 2015/09/16. At the bottom of the post I have shared a small sample of the data.

Comment: Your ogr2ogr commands in a way work for me with GDAL trunk version (2.1). However, only 6 points and 3 multipolygons are found. I believe that GDAL reports the last geometry that is identifies http://www.gdal.org/drv_gml.html. It might be possible to edit the .gfs file so that two geometries are found but unfortunately I do not know how.

Comment: I have been looking at the .GFS-file as well, but I do not know how I can edit this in a way that both geometries are taken. Does someone know this?

Comment: GDAL developers should know and they follow gdal-dev mailing list.

Answer (score 3):

I have asked the question on the GDAL-dev mailing list and got an answer and this worked for me. Here it is:

By default when parsing a GML file without a side .xsd file (or if it cannot
understand the .xsd file), the GML driver will only report the "last" geometry
element in a feature (should perhaps be improved, but that's another story).

You can manually workaround that by explictly define in the .gfs file that
OGR produces the first time it reads a GML file the following, which will define
explictly where to find geometries.

```
<GMLFeatureClassList>
  <GMLFeatureClass>
    <Name>BuildingPart</Name>
    <ElementPath>BuildingPart</ElementPath>
    <SRSName>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992</SRSName>

<!-- beginning of additions -->
    <GeomPropertyDefn>
        <Name>geometrie2dGrondvlak</Name>
        <ElementPath>geometrie2dGrondvlak</ElementPath>
        <Type>MultiPolygon</Type>
    </GeomPropertyDefn>
    <GeomPropertyDefn>
        <Name>plaatsingspunt</Name>
        <ElementPath>nummeraanduidingreeks|Nummeraanduidingreeks|nummeraanduidingreeks|Label|positie|Labelpositie|plaatsingspunt</ElementPath>
        <Type>Point</Type>
    </GeomPropertyDefn>
<!-- end of additions -->
[... unmodified rest of file ... ]
```