# How should I write a .gfs for a .gml file that has multiple Points in a single feature?

Tags: gdal, postgresql, ogr2ogr, gml

I have a .gml file that I need to parse into a Postgres database using ogr2ogr.

The command I use is:

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=mydb active_schema=myschema user=myuser password=mypass" myfile.gml -overwrite -progress -gt 1000000 --config PG_USE_COPY YES
```

This works, but it only parses the last point in case a feature has multiple points, e.g.:

```xml
...rest of the file

<imgeo:Label>
    <imgeo:tekst>Kerkstraat</imgeo:tekst>
    <imgeo:positie>
    <imgeo:Labelpositie>
        <imgeo:plaatsingspunt><gml:Point xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"> <gml:pos>19301.055 363748.087</gml:pos> </gml:Point></imgeo:plaatsingspunt>
        <imgeo:hoek>1.9</imgeo:hoek>
    </imgeo:Labelpositie>
    </imgeo:positie>
    <imgeo:positie>
    <imgeo:Labelpositie>
        <imgeo:plaatsingspunt><gml:Point xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"> <gml:pos>19348.648 363734.901</gml:pos> </gml:Point></imgeo:plaatsingspunt>
        <imgeo:hoek>2.7</imgeo:hoek>
    </imgeo:Labelpositie>
    </imgeo:positie>
</imgeo:Label>

rest of the file...
```

In the .gfs file that ogr2ogr creates it does pick-up that the `hoek` tag can occur multiple times:

```xml
<PropertyDefn>
  <Name>hoek</Name>
  <ElementPath>openbareRuimteNaam|Label|positie|Labelpositie|hoek</ElementPath>
  <Type>RealList</Type>
</PropertyDefn>
```

But for the geo-property it does no such thing.
I have now manually defined it as below, but this only picks up the last point and places that in the database for that feature.

```xml
<GeomPropertyDefn>
  <Name>plaatsingspunt</Name>
  <ElementPath>openbareRuimteNaam|Label|positie|Labelpositie|plaatsingspunt</ElementPath>
  <Type>Point</Type>
</GeomPropertyDefn>
```

How should I write the property definition in the .gfs file such that it picks up both the points associated in the future?

I've worked through the [gfs syntax manual](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gml.html#syntax-of-gfs-files) but could not find a way to tackle this problem.

I have uploaded a subset of the file here. It's complete, but it has a subset of the features: https://pastebin.com/raw/LkeP2SZh

Comment: Maybe the GMLAS driver https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gmlas.html can resolve the original schema. you can try first with `ogrinfo GMLAS:myfile.gml`. It may be better to delete the gfs file first.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that doesn't work. If in my `ogr2ogr` command I replace `myfile.gml` with `GMLAS:myfile.gml` a multide of tables is created for data that is not in the GML itself, but probably referenced somewhere, it starts spewing errors and ends after more than 1000 errors have been reported.

Comment: The GMLAS driver has many options https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gmlas.html#open-options. Remove_unused_layers and remove_unused_fields would probable shorten the output. There is a similar question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173329/converting-multi-geometry-gml-with-ogr2ogr-not-working but I fear that the answer does not help you. The GDAL datamodel probably does not support a list of points. Could you still share some test data?

Comment: I have seen the related question, it helped me for another file that has multiple geometry fields, but it's different from my case where a feature has a list of points. I have edited my question to include a sample of the file.

Comment: I fear that the GDAL data model cannot handle this. The geometry type is something like array of points and GDAL cannot support that even it supports several geometry fields, each with one simple geometry. I suggest to write mail to gdal-dev mailing list and ask what could be done. The GML schemas in your test data are extraordinary well defined and this command runs without a single error which is amazing `ogr2ogr -f gpkg many_points2.gpkg GMLAS:many_points.gml -oo remove_unused_layers=yes -oo remove_unused_fields=yes`. Now all the data and relations are in GPKG but it looks hard to use them.

Answer (score 0):

A solution on the same problem can be to use a gfs file without defining a geometry type, and define a (temporary) points attribute as a stringlist. Afterwards in PostgreSQL a geometry column can be added and set to a geometry derived from the temporary field.

```xml
<PropertyDefn>
  <Name>labelpositieplaatsingspunten_list</Name>
  <ElementPath>openbareRuimteNaam|Label|positie|Labelpositie|plaatsingspunt|Point|pos</ElementPath>
  <Type>StringList</Type>
</PropertyDefn>
```